# How to add server-side typescript files to Angular 7 project and build automatically?

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I started a `ng new my-app` using the angular CLI and got the default directory structure.

Now I write a server-side script `server.js` at the folder root to connect to database and return info to my `data.service.ts`.

I run `ng build` to compile and generate the `dist` folder, then I run the application with `node server.js` to serve the `/dist/my-app/index.html` file.

The server-side script basically runs ExpressJS and serve the REST APIs and also the Angular application.

Pretty standard stuff.

Now my server-side script is becoming huge and I want to put the the server.js into a new `src/server` folder alongside the `src/app`, `src/assets`, `src/environments` folders.

How can I make `ng build` automatically build my server.ts and other server-side typescript files and put them into, say, `dist/server` folder?

Answer (score 0):

*Question* - Why do you want to use `ng build` to build your server side project?

I understand that you use typescript now for your server, so i guess you have tsconfig.json file...

So, In your tsconfig.json file, the **include** section describes which directories to compile.
After configuring the tsconfig file, you have to use **tsc** command to compile your typescript code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would you configure the folders and build commands then? My objective is to have the server and client both in a single application project. Ideally, there should be only 1 package.json and 1 tsconfig.json; or the build command should run at the root only and need not be run multiple times.

Comment: why dont you create another project for your server-side?